# Query regarding regex for quotes

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of the form:

```
"String \\r\\n more text \\ \\ \" abc "
```

In this string I want to remove all backslash except one with quotes i.e. `\"`. Is there some way I can write a regex for it. I want my final string t look like

```
"String rn more text   \" abc "
```

I tried using:  `'\\[^\"]*'` but it does not help

Comment: Use a regexp that matches backslash with a negative lookahead for `"`.

Comment: so your expected output is `"String rn more text    \" abc \""`?

Comment: you mean something like this '[^\"]*'

Comment: @JoranBeasley: yes

Comment: Let's be careful here, because it's easy to confuse the REPRESENTATION of the data with the CONTENTS of the data.  For example, if your string happens to print the way you show it, it probably does not contain any double backslashes at all, and probably does not contain "backslash double quote".  When Python displays a string as "\\r\\n", it contains 4 characters: backslash "r" backslash "n".  It just DISPLAYS the backslashes as being doubled.  So, exactly how are you displaying that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned just use negative lookahead

```
re.sub('\\(?!")','',myString)
```

this matches a backslash ... as long as it is not followed by a quote (but only matches one character)

see also : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-regex-lookahead/

Also I would heed @timroberts comment wisely ... you need to really be sure of whats actually in the string ...

Comment: Can you also explain. I am new to regex so understanding will be really useful. By negative lookahead you mean ?!

Comment: yes that is correct